# Spatially clipping Polygons using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, clip

I am using ArcMap.

How can I spatially clip the polygon shapes outlined in red marking so that the blue polygons outside the red perimeter are deleted (red marking is just made with snipping tool pen)?

The clipped blue polygons need to share the same boundary as the purple polygons and there are gaps between some of the "islands" of purple polygons (i.e. they are not connected). Also, the blue and purple polygons are in 2 different layers (shapefiles) and there is overlap between them.

[image]

Comment: Are all the polygons in the same layer ? Did the blue and purple polygon overlap ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. It's important to always include the exact release of ArcGIS in use and to specify your license level in the question.

Comment: The blue polygons are in a different layer from the purple polygons and there is overlap between the blue and purple polygons.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't have a polygon boundary representing the red color to use it as a clip polygon. Therefore, the only option you have is the manual editing.

To get what you are looking for, you need to enable/start editing the blue polygon layer and use [Cut polygons tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/splitting-a-polygon.htm) along with [Trace tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/creating-segments-by-tracing-features.htm).

The cut polygons tool will be used to cut the blue polygons where no purple polygons overlap, and the Trace tool will be used to trace the purple polygons while the Cut polygon is still enabled.

You can refer to the *Cutting polygons by tracing overlapping features* section in this [ArcGIS Blog: Getting the most out of editing in ArcGIS 10: Tracing features](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/data-management/getting-the-most-out-of-editing-in-arcgis-10-tracing-features/) to see some illustration of what I am explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have the red boundary polygons as a layer you can do two things:

- if the red boundary is along the boundary of blue polygons, you can simply select those polygons and do a clip function with your purple polygons.
- if the red boundary is not along the boundary of blue polygons, you will have to edit your blue boundaries and then clip it with the purple polygons.